How to install langchain-openai that is compatible with existing openai installation?
I am migrating to langchain version 0.2 in my project, which now requires installing LLM models separately. I attempted to install langchain-openai using:
pipenv install langchain-openai

However, this conflicts with another package in my environment:
openai = "==1.3.5"

It seems I need to find a compatible version of langchain-openai that works with openai==1.3.5 or consider upgrading openai without breaking my current code.
How can I determine which version of the openai SDK is compatible with specific versions of langchain-openai? I've checked PyPI, but I couldn't find detailed information about dependencies between these packages.
Terminal output:
pipenv install langchain_openai
Loading .env environment variables...
Installing langchain_openai...
Resolving langchain_openai...
Added langchain-openai to Pipfile's [packages] ...
Installation Succeeded
Pipfile.lock (244de0) out of date, updating to (fca94c)...
Locking [packages] dependencies...
Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
Locking Failed!
[==  ] Locking...False
CRITICAL:pipenv.patched.pip._internal.resolution.resolvelib.factory:Cannot install -r C:\Users\MUBASH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pipenv-uudymc5q-requirements\pipenv-ustatlmc-constraints.txt (line 48), -r C:\Users\MUBASH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pipenv-uudymc5q-requirements\pipenv-ustatlmc-constraints.txt (line 68) and openai==1.3.5 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.


I found a way to determine the compatible version of the openai SDK for a specific langchain-openai version:

Visit the PyPI page for langchain-openai.
Go to the Release history section and select a version of interest.
Click on Source Code (or go to the repository directly).
Navigate to the /libs/partners/openai directory if you accessed the main repo; the source code link will take you directly to this directory.
Open the pyproject.toml file, where you can find the exact openai version that the langchain-openai version depends on.
If needed, switch the branch/tags to another version to check compatibility with different versions.

This method allowed me to identify the compatible version for my project. However, things don’t end there. After selecting the langchain version you found this directory in, you may need to upgrade openai to a compatible version.
In my searches, starting from langchain v0.1, the openai dependency is set to ^1.6.1. Versions below this likely use the old structure, so upgrading might not be feasible.
The real question now is how much effort it will take to upgrade openai. In hindsight, using langchain has introduced significant overhead, and the trade-off may not be worth it.
https://community.openai.com/t/conflict-between-langchain-openai-and-openai-1-3-5-in-pipenv-how-to-resolve-dependency-issues/929268
